# shannon interpolation in image processing

Tags: image-processing, matlab, interpolation

I tried to implement Shannon interpolation on a 2D array.

First, implemented it on a 1D signal, just for sanity-check:

```
t = -7:7;
t2= -7:0.01:7;
figure
plot(t, sin(pi*t / 3))
upSamp = zeros(size(t2));
for iT = 1:length(t2)
    upSamp(iT) = sum(sinc(t2(iT) - t) .* sin(pi*t / 3));
end
hold
plot(t2, upSamp)
```

[image]

Looks ok.

Then, implementation on a 2D array. The reference array is:

```
figure
surf(sin(pi*T1 / 3).*sin(pi*T2 / 3))
```

[image]

Then the interpolation is done by a convolution with a Sombrero function:

```
[T12, T22] = meshgrid(t2, t2);
val = zeros(size(T12));
for iInterp=1:numel(T12)
    xdist = (T12(iInterp) - T1);
    ydist = (T22(iInterp) - T2);
    val(iInterp) = sum(sinc(sqrt(xdist.^2 + ydist.^2)) .* sin(pi*T1 / 3).*sin(pi*T2 / 3), 'all');
end
figure;surf(val, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
```

seems to work good only on the edges :(

Any suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error source is the kernel function, which should be a multiplication of two 1D sincs (without rotational symmetry) instead of the Sombrero function, which is a sinc function with rotational symmetry.

[image]

[image]